# Below Android API-21,convertToTranslucent method of Activity is invalid ？

Tags: android

I want to dynamically change the background of Activity for transparent.

Above API-21,`convertToTranslucent` method is useful.

But it is invalid below API-21.

This is my calling code：

```
public static void convertActivityToTranslucentBeforeL(Activity activity) {
    try {
        Class<?>[] classes = Activity.class.getDeclaredClasses();
        Class<?> translucentConversionListenerClazz = null;
        for (Class clazz : classes) {
            if (clazz.getSimpleName().contains("TranslucentConversionListener")) {
                translucentConversionListenerClazz = clazz;
            }
        }
        Method method = Activity.class.getDeclaredMethod("convertToTranslucent",
                translucentConversionListenerClazz);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(activity, new Object[] {
                null
        });
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

convertToTranslucent method of Activity

```
public void convertToTranslucent(TranslucentConversionListener callback) {
    try {
        mTranslucentCallback = callback;
        mChangeCanvasToTranslucent =
                ActivityManagerNative.getDefault().convertToTranslucent(mToken);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // pass
    }
}
```

And I found that the value of the mChangeCanvasToTranslucent after the call was false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using some internal Android function, that was not existent in previous versions. You should never be using internal functions.
A simple work around would be to set your activity as always translucent, and set your layout background to solid. Then dynamically change the layout background opacity.